# How to import Route53 record that contains underscores

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have an existing Route53 record that I'm attempting to import. Example of the record: `50200._dkey.mydomain.com`

I create the resource like so:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "50200_dkey_txt" {
  zone_id = aws_route53_zone.mydomain_com.zone_id
  name = "50200._dkey.mydomain.com"
  type = "TXT"
  ttl = "300"
  records = ["text_record_contents"]
}
```

Then, I run the import:

```
terraform import module.route53.aws_route53_record.50200_dkey_txt Z0N3ID0FZ0NE_50200._dkey.mydomain.com_TXT
```

I'm greeted with the following error:

```
╷
│ Error: Attribute name required
│ 
│   on <import-address> line 1:
│    1: module.route53.aws_route53_record.50200_dkey_txt
│ 
│ Dot must be followed by attribute name.
╵
```

I'm assuming the underscore in the record is the culprit. If I'm correct in assuming so, is there a way to escape the underscore character or format it in such way to make terraform read it in literal form? I attempted to wrap it in single quotes, but received the same error.

Comment: I think it's the number that's the problem.

Comment: @MarkoE thanks. Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terraform does not allow a resource name that starts with a digit, because when referring to resources elsewhere in the module and on the command line Terraform (similar to many other languages) treats a digit as the start of a number, rather than as the start of a name.

Normally Terraform would catch this when parsing your configuration, but I think because you are using `terraform import` as your first command to run here it's the command line parsing that is coming first, and therefore unfortunately raising a less helpful error.

This is what other Terraform commands would've shown, due to the configuration being invalid:

```
╷
│ Error: Invalid resource name
│ 
│   on example.tf line 1, in resource "aws_route53_record" "50200_dkey":
│    1: resource "aws_route53_record" "50200_dkey" {
│ 
│ A name must start with a letter or underscore and may contain only letters,
│ digits, underscores, and dashes.
╵
```

The solution then is to change the resource name to be a valid name, such as by adding some letters to the start of it as a prefix:

```
resource "aws_route53_record" "txt_50200_dkey" {
  # ...
}
```

Then when you run `terraform import` you should specify the new resource name, but you should be able to keep the same *remote* identifier (the second argument) so that Terraform will bind the given remote object to the given local address:

```
terraform import "module.route53.aws_route53_record.txt_50200_dkey" "Z0N3ID0FZ0NE_50200._dkey.mydomain.com_TXT"
```

(I'm actually not sure how `aws_route53_record` in particular interprets its "remote ID" strings, so I've just copied what you tried verbatim here. With the invalid resource name fixed this may expose a new error about the ID string, but I probably won't know the answer to that one if so. )

Comment: Changing the resource name worked. Funny, I've ran into this a while back and the error explicitly complained about the resource name starting with a digit and I forgot. Thanks for your very helpful answer, Martin. I feel very silly, but happy to get this issue off my plate!

Answer (score 1):

The import command is slightly off. It should be:

```
terraform import module.route53.aws_route53_record.50200_dkey Z0N3ID0FZ0NE_50200._dkey.mydomain.com_TXT
```

Note the form for the namespace is `<optional module>.<optional module declared name>.<resource type>.<resource name>["<optional iterator key>"]`.

Comment: You're correct that the command is off, but that is not the problem. I actually didn't paste the resource name correctly and it is actually `50200_dkey_txt`
I will edit the question to reflect that.